# Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a `Xamarin.Forms` Project

I'm trying to play an .mp3 file with the plugin `Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer`.

I am attempting to do this out of the Assets folder of my `Xamarin.Forms` Project

When I use the following code:

```
            var player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
            player.Load("select.mp3");
```

I receive this error:

> `Java.IO.FileNotFoundException`

However If I use the `AssetManager` class to open the `.mp3` file I receive the same error:

```
        AssetManager assets = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets;
        //var filename = assets.Open("select.mp3");
        Stream input = assets.Open("select.mp3");

        //var newfile = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "select.mp3");
```

Some code is commented out to show the different variations I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, create an interface in the PCL.

```
    public  interface IReadStream
    {
        Stream ReadStreamFromAsset();
    }
```

Then  achieve the interface in the android platform.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ReadStreamService))]
namespace MyPopUpPageDemo.Droid
{
    class ReadStreamService : IReadStream
    {
        public Stream ReadStreamFromAsset()
        {
          
            AssetManager assets = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets;

            return assets.Open("app_sound.mp3");
        }
    }
}
```

Please notice mp3 file `Build Action` to `AndroidAsset`

[image]

Then use dependenceService in the PCL.

```
           ISimpleAudioPlayer player;
        Stream stream;
        public MainPage()
        {
           
            InitializeComponent();

            player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();
            stream = DependencyService.Get<IReadStream>().ReadStreamFromAsset();
            player.Load(stream);

        }
```

When button is clicked it, play the audio

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            player.Play();
          

        }
```

Comment: Could you please go into more detail for me as to what a PCL (Portable Class library) is? And where I can find it?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Leon, I was also wondering why the instructions described in the following link did not work for me? As they are found on the Microsoft.com website.   https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/adding-sound-xamarin-forms-app/

Comment: His demo code, put the audio to the **shared library** not **Android Asset**.